# How to evaluate a function in Python using numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of randomly generated x's and y's and I want to evaluate each pair at some function. How do I do that using numpy? I tried the code below, but it does not work.

What I want is an array of func(x_i,y_i).

```
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)

func = np.array((math.exp(-2 * x) * math.cos(2 * y)))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We like to see more than 'doesnt work'.  We want to see the error, and if possible, to see you trying to understand the error.  If the error occurs in long expression, try evaluating pieces to see exactly which is giving problems.  Is it the `np.array`?  or the `math.cos(...)`?

Comment: Spend more time reading `numpy` basics.  Thinking in terms of evaluating single values or pairs as your `math` function requires, results in slow code.  You want to become familiar with the operators and methods that work with whole arrays.  The switch from `math.cos` to `np.cos` is just one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `math`, use `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)

func = np.exp(-2 * x) * np.cos(2 * y)

>>> func.shape
    (100,)
```

That is, `func[i]` contains the result of your function using `x[i]` and `y[i]` as input.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `np.array()` wrapper?

Comment: Oopss, one mistake due to copy/paste it.

Comment: How do I compare the values I have in the func variable with the values in the y variable?

I tried indicator = (y <= func), but it does return anything

Comment: Given the fact that `y` and `func` should now be `numpy` arrays, you can use any operation on them that `numpy` offers. For instance, `comparison = y <= func` makes `comparison` a boolean array of the same shape as `y`. What do you mean that it doesn't return anything?